# Symlink-ing into addons folder

Tags: add-on

I am developing software on OS X.

One component requires blender, and it requires a custom plug-in which I have had to write, and which I have to continually modify.

Now it's a very bad workflow if I am modifying in-place, because it is outside of the project tree. So when I back up my project I'm not backing up the blender plug-in, as it is in:

```
/Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.69/scripts/addons/
```

What I try to do is create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /path/to/myproj/blenderplugin \
        /Applications/blender.app/Contents/MacOS/2.69/scripts/addons/pi_project
```

But then blender can't find it.

Does this qualify as a bug?

Comment: Works for me on linux. What are the exact steps you took? (It sounds silly, but did you remember to refresh blender after symlinking?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a symlink you can just point to a /scripts/ directory in **User Preferences > File**

[image: File path to alternate scripts directory]

After setting the path be sure to **Save User Settings**. Doing this will let you place your scripts in the folder designated, and leave the default folder alone.

Your folder structure should look like:

```
scripts/
  addons/
  addons_contrib/
  startup/
  presets/
```

Not all sub-directories are required, but you should have at least /scripts/addons/